# jumpy validation accuracy graph

Tags: deep-learning, cnn, pytorch, accuracy, graphs

helo,
i have a very weird problem.
my validation accuracy graph is very jumpy, and i dont know how to fix it
this is the graph:

[image]

this is a multi label problem. i calculate accuracy with 0.5 threshold
i think that the problem related to my loss function
(i needed to minimize even one class success in the model prediction, and not only when he success in all of them)

i have a costume loss function:

```py
    def loss_function(predictions, labels, batch_size):
        eps = 0.000000000000000000000000001
        losses = 0
        k = len(lebels[0])
        ones = torch.ones(1, 1).expand(batch_size, k).cuda()
        loss1 = -((ones-labels)*(((ones-predictions)+(eps)).log())).sum(dim=1)
        prod = (ones-labels)*k - labels*((predictions+ eps).log())
        loss2 = torch.min(prod, dim=1)[0]
        losses = (loss1 + loss2).sum()
        return losses / batch_size
```

i hope someone can understand the problem
thank you very much.

Comment: What's your batch size?  It's strange that accuracy jumps up to 100% fairly often.  Indicates that your batches may be too small, or your training data may not be very well stratified.

Comment: @zachdj tnx for your answer! actually, my batches are big, but what do you mean by not be very well stratified? can you explain a little bit more?

Comment: If the data is stratified, then each batch will have roughly equal representation of class labels.  So suppose your dataset is 30% class A, 45% class B, and 25% class C.  Then a _stratified_ mini-batch of 100 samples should have approximately 30 As, 45 Bs, and 25 Cs.

Comment: Now suppose your model is highly biased, and almost always predicts the majority class.  It would achieve 100% accuracy on batches that have samples all with label B, but the accuracy would drop on other, more diverse batches.

This sort-of matches the behavior seen in your accuracy graph, where accuracy bounces between 100% and 40% for awhile.